# Как очистить mAutoComplete

Tags: java, android

На форме имеется mAutoComplete, после ввода некоторого текста в него, выбирается значение из выпадающего списка и происходит переход на другую activity. 
Проблема в том, что если вернуться на предыдущую activity(где вводился текст),  текст остаётся и я никак не могу очистить его.
Пытался так, но это не помогало:

```
mAutoComplete.setText("");
```

вставлял эту строчку в метод onCreate. Как мне очистить текст в mAutoComplete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорей всего остается из-за того, что вы пытаетесь это сделать в OnCreate. Попробуйте в onResume так:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAutoComplete.setText("");
}
```